# Error Installation MRO by CodUP module on Odo 12.0

Tags: python, odoo, method-resolution-order

I try to install MRO module but I get this error

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 757, in parse
   self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
 File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 573, in _tag_record
   model = self.env[rec_model]
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 820, in __getitem__
   return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
 File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 176, in __getitem__
   return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'procurement.rule'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 653, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 312, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 695, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 344, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 337, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 938, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 517, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 966, in      call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 749, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 736, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-61>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 71, in    check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 442, in    button_immediate_install
     return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 535, in    _button_immediate_function
     modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 426, in load_modules
     loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 318, in    load_marked_modules
     perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 224, in load_module_graph
     load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 68, in load_data
     tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 801, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 864, in convert_xml_import
     obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 754, in parse
    self.parse(rec, mode)
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 763, in parse
   exc_info[2]
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 86, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 757, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 573, in _tag_record
    model = self.env[rec_model]
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 820, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 176, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
 odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "procurement.rule" while parsing /odoo/odoo-   server/addons/mro/mro_data.xml:59, near
   <record id="rule_wh_asset" model="procurement.rule">
                <field name="name">WH: Stock -&gt; Asset</field>
               <field name="action">move</field>
               <field name="picking_type_id"   ref="stock.picking_type_internal"/>
                 <field name="location_src_id"  ref="stock.stock_location_stock"/>
                 <field name="location_id" ref="asset.stock_location_assets"/>
                 <field name="route_id" ref="mro.route_maintenance"/>
         </record>
```

I installed asset module as dependencies but nothing change

OS Debian 9
same installation but Odoo 11.0
works fine

same installation but Odoo 10.0
works fine

also tried to uninstall, purge and reinstall but nothing change new

Can anyone help me or have any idea to solve the problem pleas
waithing for your reply

thanks

regards

MD

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Maudal78! 
The procurement.rule has been renamed to stock.rule in Odoo v12. This is why the old code does not work in Odoo 12. See commit https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/827958a8902589246dd741341ce1bc5465059909 for details.

You, CodUp team or someone need to make changes to the module for it to be compatible. There already is a branch for Odoo 12.0 in the module’s repo at https://github.com/codup/odoo-eam, but it does not contain changes for this.